# How to move the y axis to the left in excel , scatter plot with x-axis log scale?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have my scatter plot with x-axis log scale like below:

[image: scatter]

I want the position of y-axis moved to the left. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

I'm doing this from memory since I don't have Excel at home.

1. Double click on graph
2. Double click on x-axis
3. On the Scale tab, have the y-axis cross the x-axis at 0.1.
4. Click OK

Comment: I usually just use an arbitrarily small crossing values (1e-9) as then the y axis will always stay at the left.

Answer (score 1):

Left click on Horizontal axis; right click and select "Format Axis...".  In the options for "Vertical axis crosses" select "Axis value" and enter the horizontal axis value you want the vertical axis to be positioned at.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  This duplicates LDC3's answer.  In this Q&A format, each answer should contribute another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Double click on graph
Double click on x-axis
On the Scale tab, have the y-axis cross the x-axis at MAXIMUM CATEGORY.
Click OK

Comment: (1) What version of Excel are you talking about?  I can’t find that interface in Excel 2013.  Can you post screenshot(s)?  (2) At maximum?  That seems counter-intuitive.  Can you explain how that makes sense? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.